# Firebase auth with Facebook OAuth credential (from Google Extension)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, oauth, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am just having fun with the new Firebase, but I'm struggling with auth system.

Because I'm trying to login user from options page of google extension, so I can't use signInWithPopup or Redirect method due (some) security reasons.

So I figure out possible solution. From options page I redirect user to my another page, where he can easily login with Firebase (by Facebook provider) - everything is OK - user obtain OAuth FB token and this page send message to extension to cache this token.

There lies the problem.

I have code like this:

```
firebase.initializeApp(FIREBASE_CONFIG);
var credential = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(token);
firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credential)
.then((data) => {
  console.log(data);
})
.catch((err) => {
  console.error(err.code);
})
```

This fire up POST request to https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/ and in response I can clearly see the error:

```
message:"INVALID_REQUEST_URI"
```

This request is fired with requestURI payload, which is in mine situation:

```
chrome-extension://kefhjfjilmodblnpnekjleceapohasdf/options.html
```

When I tried to fire this request from terminal with CURL and I faked the requestURI with 'http://localhost' everything is OK and I got correct data.

Do you have any ideas, how can I achieve proper behavior?

Thanks a lot.

P.S: I'm using Firebase.js 3.0.5-rc.2

Comment: FYI: 

Today I got response from firebase support:

'Unfortunately, it is currently a known issue that Firebase Auth won't work on Chrome extensions. We are working on fixing the issue, but I can't give you any timeline on when it will be done.'